# Headphones built in Mic doesn't work

Tags: audio, headphones

I got Beats Studio, They work just fine except the mic which doesn't work at all, My pc asks me what did i plug in so i have to choose one thing:

[image]

But then as i said the mic doesn't work, even if i tick "Mic in" instead.

I also tried Line in, No luck.

I appreciate any help!

*P.S. I have 2 front jacks, one for microphone and the other for headphones.*

Comment: Did you plug the microphone into the back at all?

Answer (score 4):

Those headphones use a [TRRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS_connector) (tip, ring, ring, sleeve) connector to carry the stereo AND the mic signal on one cable.

Most motherboards' audio jacks are TRS (stereo) jacks, and don't have the hardware to deal with the second ring (which carries the mic signals).

You'll need a TRRS female to dual TRS male breakout cable:

[image: trrs breakout]

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a place to buy this cable... Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Amazon, Walmart, Radio Shack, eBay, your local stereo/home theatre store, etc. :)  Try googling "TRRS female to dual TRS male breakout cable", it finds me many matches of places to buy one from.